# Blurry font in first question pop-up

Tags: bug, popups

I just posted my first question and got this pop-up

[image]

The font of the pop-up looks terrible blurry, while the rest of the page is sharp and crisp.

(my browser is Opera, in case it matters)

Comment: What OS and device do you have? Did you zoom-in the browser page?

Comment: The pop-up, even zoomed, is [razor sharp on FF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjaa7.jpg) Android.

Comment: @Rob that is not the same popup though ...

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask mac and no zoom in by browser

Comment: @Rob yeah, I tried to check how those dialogs are delivered. I didn't check all client-side stuff so I'm not 100% sure if all pop-ups are send the same. It seems logical that you're right yet I wouldn't be surprised if the code and content is different from the pop-up the OP shows and the one you show.

Comment: @rene, It seems that this is a thing for some circumstances: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22144937/3648282 or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58119/63507 - from a [search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=blurry+font). I think we need to know if it's just one pop-up only or if this occurs in various places to determine if it's the *delivery* or *rendering* (system setting) (which end is the problem). If the DPI is misread, (and it is for high DPI displays - mine included) the font could be misscaled and smoothed leaving it fuzzy. Unfortunately I have no question to ask ...

Comment: If this is on Windows, then I'd recommend adjusting the ClearType setting, but since this is on Mac... I only remembered seeing this kind of issue with unsupported display resolution, but that should affect the whole display, not only this specific pop-up. Also just to make sure you're using the latest version of Opera since [that's what SE supports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). If possible, try with other browsers to pinpoint the issue.